# Compressing android studio file

Tags: android, ubuntu

I want to upload my android studio project online on a site. The original size of project is 2.9 GB and when i convert it into a zip file it reduced to 2.1 GB but the uploading size limit is less than 20 mb. So please tell me the way to reduce my file. I am using ubuntu operating system.

Comment: remove build folders and .git file on taking backups. e.g. https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture it's a random project without any build and .git folder

Answer (score 0):

Go to project folder and remove **`build`** folder then go to `app` folder and remove this **`build`** folder and .git folder